# SQL query: get first 20 and number of total items in one query

Tags: mysql, database

is ite possible to make an mysql query in which you get the latest 20 items AND the number of all the items, without using 2 queries. The less queries, the better, not? I need it for pagination.

```
SELECT item.* FROM #__gallery_items AS item ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Maybe the best is that each row has an extra column called 'totalitems', with the total number of items?

Is it possible and if yes, how? Thanks!

Comment: chances are the answer is "no"

Comment: "Maybe the best is that each row has an extra column called 'totalitems', with the total number of items?" no... no... no...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS item.* FROM #__gallery_items AS item ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,20

SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

Two queries, it's the only way ^^

Comment: Umm...I may be being daft, but could you not return it using a subquery? Does MySQL not support subqueries on SELECTS? It's not efficient, but it is possible, isn't it?

Comment: @ndtreviv It is possible. But why would you do that?

Comment: Hmm perhaps but anyway it wouldn't be very effective unless you MUST use ONE query!

Comment: Agreed - it wouldn't be more efficient on large data sets, and whether it would be efficient on smaller ones would depend on connection pooling etc. HOWEVER, it does answer the question - if you MUST use ONE query...

Comment: So using 2 queries is just as effective as combining it into one with a subquery?

Comment: Depends upon the data set size and the overheads of managing DB connections, wouldn't it? I'm not 100% convinced myself, but consider: If there were very few rows, which takes more time/resources between opening, closing, cleaning a connection or performing a subquery. As before, personally I'd choose two queries all the time, but if you HAD to use ONE query, this would do it.

Comment: @Bert using 2 queries in this case is more efficient in any way (if you don't consider caching and the like).

Comment: http://www.phpdevblog.net/2009/06/mysql-pagination-sql-calc-found-rows-vs-count-query.html weird..!

Answer (score 2):

```
drop table if exists gallery_items;
create table gallery_items
(
item_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
title varchar(255) not null
)
engine=innodb;

insert into gallery_items (title) values 
('p1'),('p2'),('p3'),('p4'),('p5'),('p6'),('p7'),('p8'),('p9'),('p10'),
('p11'),('p12'),('p13'),('p14'),('p15');


select 
 gi.*,
 c.counter
from 
 gallery_items gi 
join( 
    select count(*) as counter from gallery_items
) c
order by 
 gi.item_id desc limit 10; -- change to 20 or whatever

 /*
item_id title  counter
======= =====  =======
15       p15    15
14       p14    15
13       p13    15
12       p12    15
11       p11    15
10       p10    15
9         p9     15
8         p8     15
7         p7     15
6         p6     15
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible to return the total number of items in a table within the same query, but you would be doing so using a sub-query, which is executed for every record. For example:

```
SELECT item.*, (select count(*) from #__gallery_items) as TOTAL_COUNT FROM #__gallery_items AS item ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

I doubt that it would be more efficient than doing two queries on a large dataset, or even on a smaller data set unless there was no form of connection pooling and the overhead of DB connection management was weighed up against executing sub queries.

So, having said this - two queries is possibly your better bet in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE FOUND_ROWS()
```

this will return all rows in a result set

Comment: Thanks, but thats another query, not? I view of performance I was hoping there was a more effective way than using two queries, just to get a number in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
```

in combination with

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

You'll always need two querys (a subquery is possible, but it is still a second query).

Comment: Agreed - a second query executed on every record. Stick with two queries is the answer of the day, I think

Answer (score 0):

SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is an option,

SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tells MySQL to calculate how many rows there would be in the result set.

So try to use query like

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS item.* FROM #__gallery_items AS item ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,20

Using SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, MySQL must calculate how many rows are in the full result set. However, this is faster than running the query again without LIMIT, because the result set need not be sent to the client.

SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() can be useful in situations when you want to restrict the number of rows that a query returns, but also determine the number of rows in the full result set without running the query again. An example is a Web script that presents a paged display containing links to the pages that show other sections of a search result. Using FOUND_ROWS() enables you to determine how many other pages are needed for the rest of the result.

Thanks!

Hussain

Comment: Hello, when I use a query like "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS item.* FROM #__gallery_items AS item ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,20", where can I find the number of the total rows? I tried it, but can't find the number in the result object.

Answer (score 0):

The two result sets represent two completely different things, so by definition, you cannot show them together (i.e. don't do it in one query). You could be adding the value via a sub query as @ndtreviv suggested, but like he said, it is highly inefficient as it will be calculated for every row there is in your table.